# htaccess to rewrite url in order to remove php extension only at the root directory and not in subdirectories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

I have a website composed as follows:

```
index.php
page1.php
page2.php
page3.php
 - images
   image1.jpg
   image2.jpg
 - style
   style.css
```

I want to write an htaccess file which can give me SEO friendly URL. In example:

- `https://example.com/page2.php` should be `https://example.com/page2`

and also:

- `https://example.com/page2.php#mytab` should be `https://example.com/page2#mytab`

But I would like to apply those rules only on the first directory, so "images" and "style" dirs can continue to be reached using the extensions.

Can somebody help? Thanks

Comment: Although you only appear to have `.php` files in the document root anyway?

Comment: yes exactly.
I am even looking for rewrite URL 1 to 1.

I mean I could even write a rule page by page. It does not matter to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You should already be linking to the files *without* the `.php` extension on your internal URLs (ie. `href="/page1"`, not `href="/page1.php"`). I'm also assuming that your URLs don't otherwise contain dots (which normally delimits the file extension).
2. Implement a rewrite to append the `.php` extension if required. This needs to go near the top of the root `.htaccess` file:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On

   # Internally rewrite extenionless URLs to append ".php" if required
   # Tests only requests (that do not contain a dot) in the root directory
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
   RewriteRule ^([^./]+)$ $1.php [L]
   ```

   Alternative for the `RewriteCond` (filesystem check):

   ```
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
   :
   ```

   Alternatively, you could remove the `RewriteCond` directive altogether to unconditionally rewrite all requests in the root (without a file extension) to append the `.php` extension.
3. (OPTIONAL) If you are changing a URL structure and removing `.php` from your URLs and the old URLs have been indexed by search engines and/or linked to by third parties then you need to also implement a redirect to remove the `.php` extension for SEO.

   Add the following immediately after the `RewriteEngine` directive above (before the internal rewrite):

   ```
   # Redirect to remove the `.php` extension inbound requests
   # Only affects the root directory
   RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
   RewriteRule ^([^./]+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
   ```

   The *condition* that tests against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable ensures we don't redirect already rewritten requests by the later rewrite and this avoiding a redirect loop.

   NB: Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.
4. Alternatively (instead of **#3**), to prevent direct access to the `.php` file and serve a 404 Not Found instead then add the following immediately after the `RewriteEngine` directive above (before the internal rewrite):

   ```
   # Prevent direct access to ".php" file and serve a 404 instead
   # Only affects the root directory
   RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
   RewriteRule ^([^./]+)\.php$ - [R=404]
   ```

---

> what is the best way to show the content of my custom 404 page every time a 404 error occurs? (I would not like to use redirect)

Use the following at the top of the `.htaccess` file, passing the full URL-path to the `ErrorDocument` directive.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error-docs/e404.php
```

The stated error document is called using an internal subrequest (there is no external redirect).

Note that this should include the `.php` file extension here - this is entirely invisible to the user.

Comment: It seems to work with common name such as "index", but it doesn't if the files contain a dash symbol - 
like my-page.php is not reached by navigating http://example.com/my-page
it gives me out a 404 not found error.

Comment: @Nino It shouldn't matter if the URL contains a dash (or hyphen). The regex `^([^./]+)$` only excludes dots and slashes (so only the first path segment is matched, excluding URLs that already contain a dot, ie. a file extension).

Comment: @Nino Do you have any other directives in the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I saw it, but it is not working. I confirm that adding .php it works, and index (without .php) works.

Comment: I don't... only 
`RewriteEngine On

# Internally rewrite extenionless URLs to append ".php" if required
# Tests only requests (that do not contain a dot) in the root directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)$ $1.php [L]`

Comment: any suggestion? @MrWhite

Comment: @Nino That's a bit odd. To clarify, all these files, including `.htaccess` are in the document root directory? Try commenting out the `RewriteCond` directive. (ie. `#RewriteCond`).

Comment: I confirm to you that now it works! Thank you so much. The only weird behaviour is that now both example.com/my-page and example.com/my-page.php are reachable. Is there a way to not make reachable the .php one?

Comment: @Nino Hhhmm curious, that would mean the filesystem check is failing for some reason. This could happen if the `.htaccess` file is not in the document root directory?! The only side-effect with removing the `RewriteCond` directive in this case it that it rewrites `<anything>` regardless of whether `<anything>.php` exists. Not necessarily a serious issue, but it is unnecessary. To prevent the `.php` URL being accessible you should implement **#3** in my answer - this redirects the request to remove `.php` from the URL.

Comment: @Nino As a test, you could try changing the `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f` directive for the following instead: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` - does that work?

Comment: I implemented the #3, but I think trying to visit a .php files should response with a 404 right? instead right now it redirect to the php-less page

Comment: @Nino Ok, it depends whether you are changing an existing URL structure or not. I've added **#4** to my answer that will serve a 404 not Found for `.php` requests instead. (Did you try changing that `RewriteCond` directive to use `REQUEST_FILENAME` instead?)

Comment: @Nino Yes, that is correct behaviour. But you can serve a 404 instead if you want (for which I have updated my answer with point **#4**). If you have never used `.php` URLs in the wild (ie. not indexed by search engines or linked to by third parties) then a 404 in acceptable, otherwise a 301 redirect would be preferable. NB: If you have previously used a 301 here (not a 302 as I suggested in my answer) then you will need to clear your browser cache since 301s are _permanent_ and cached persistently by the browser.

Comment: I can happily tell you that everything works correctly! Just to finish this template, what is the best way to show the content of my custom 404 page every time a 404 error occurs? (I would not like to use redirect)

Comment: @Nino That's great. (I'm curious, did the change to the `RewriteCond` directive work? Or was it no different?) I've updated my answer with regards to setting a custom 404 error document.

Comment: I haven't tried because I solved first commenting what you suggested and secondary adding a virtual host to my local server so I was sure to be in the root path. I want to suggest as a solution for the 404 this on top of htaccess:

`ErrorDocument 404 /e404`

it works if in the root path there is a page called e404.php which follows the previous rules

Comment: @Nino I've already updated my answer regarding the use of `ErrorDocument`. As stated, you should really use `/e404.php` in the `ErrorDocument` directive, not `/e404`, to avoid the dependency on other directives.